sudoを実行した際にユーザーが設定した$PATHを引き継ぐには？
Debian 12で、sudoを実行した際にユーザーが設定した$PATHを引き継ぎたい
試したことA
$ sudo visudo

変更箇所
#Defaults       secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
Defaults        env_keep += "PATH"
ファイル保存した後、「sudo: visudo: コマンドが見つかりません」エラーメッセージが表示されるようになりました。
試したことB
$ sudo visudo

変更箇所
Defaults        env_keep += "PATH"
secure_pathをコメントアウトせず「Defaults        env_keep += "PATH"」だけを追加してみましたが、sudoを実行した際にユーザーが設定した$PATHは引き継がれませんでした。

https://ja.manpages.org/sudo/8 によると-Eオプションでユーザーの環境を引き継げるようなのですが、それではダメなのでしょうか

ユーザーの環境を引き継げるなら、それでよいです

sudoには-Eオプションがあり、大抵の環境変数は引き継いで実行することができます。
https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/manpages-ja/sudo.8.ja.html
sudoなど一般的なコマンドはまずmanコマンドで調べることをおすすめします。

初めて知りました。設定でどうにかして引き継ぐものだと思っていました……
